# How do I sort hyperlinks in a DataTable numerically?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following hyperlink grid-view column that needs to be sorted numerically by IncidentId.  Is there a way to keep the data as a hyperlink and only sort by the IncidentId? When I use the following javascript function to sort it "numerical" it breaks and the column will not sort.  If I declare sType as "string" or "html" it sorts, but it alphabetizes the data rather than a numerical sort, in other words, it will list it as 93, 82, 71, 40, 123, 122, 121 rather than 123, 122, 121, 93, 82, 71, 40.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Incident ID:" DataNavigateUrlFields="IncidentId" 
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="view.aspx?id={0}" DataTextField="IncidentId"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#GridViewIncidents').dataTable({
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": true,
            "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "numerical", "aTargets": [0]}]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Use a plugin, perhaps: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting

Comment: Also found this on Google: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/367/bug-sort-number-column-and-stype/p1

Comment: I will take a look at the forum discussion.  Thanks for these links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the default comparers for the datatables sort function.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.aTypes.unshift(
    function (sData) {
        if (sData !== null && sData.match('^<.*[0-9]+</.*>$')) {
            return 'intComparer';
        }
        return null;
    }
);
```

the above code will find any integer wrapped in an html tag and tell Datatables to use a custom comparer function.

We then need to define the compaere functions for this:

```
    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['intComparer-asc'] = function (a, b) {
        var value1 = parseInt(getInnerHTML(a));
        var value2 = parseInt(getInnerHTML(b));
        return ((value1 < value2) ? -1 : ((value1 > value2) ? 1 : 0));
    };

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['intComparer-desc'] = function (a, b) {
        var value1 = parseInt(getInnerHTML(a));
        var value2 = parseInt(getInnerHTML(b));
        return ((value1 < value2) ? 1 : ((value1 > value2) ? -1 : 0));
    };
```

This strips the tags out and sorts by numeric value.

Just put all this code in a script tag before you set up your table and it should work!

Comment: getInnerHTML is not defined

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to first define an `addType` extension point:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt, {
    addType: function (options) {
        var optionsSpecified = options != null && options.name && options.detect && options.compare;
        if (!optionsSpecified) {
            alert('addColumnType: options are not specified correctly.');
        } else {
            this.aTypes.unshift(function (sData) {
                return options.detect(sData) ? options.name : null;
            });

            this.oSort[options.name + '-asc'] = function (x, y) {
                return options.compare(x, y);
            };

            this.oSort[options.name + '-desc'] = function (x, y) {
                return options.compare(x, y) * -1;
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Thereafter we define the extension for recognising integer links, using the above extension point:

```
(function () {
    var linkRegex = new RegExp("^<a.*>([0-9]+)</a>$");

    function parseIntLink(sData) {
        var result = linkRegex.exec(sData);
        return result == null ? NaN : parseInt(result[1], 10);
    }

    jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.addType({
        name: 'int-link',
        detect: function (sData) {
            return !isNaN(parseIntLink(sData));
        },
        compare: function (x, y) {
            return parseIntLink(x) - parseIntLink(y);
        }
    });
})();
```

Please see this [blog](http://tahirhassan.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/datatables-sorting-function.html) for more details. (Disclaimer: it is my blog).